# Why is chromedriver browser invisible?

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run basic selenium chromedriver script.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();

//Deleting all the cookies
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

//Specifiying pageLoadTimeout and Implicit wait
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//launching the specified URL
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

//Locating the elements using name locator for the text box
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("YouTube");

//name locator for google search button
WebElement searchIcon = driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));
searchIcon.click();   

driver.quit();
```

I'm using ubuntu, eclipse and maven to install project dependencies, which are these:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
       <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.0</version>
    <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
   </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I've tried many, any versions I would say. The problem is that when I launch the script it behaves as if the "--headless" flag is enabled. It runs, takes control from the main window(it fades for a second) then goes through instructins and fails here.

> driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("YouTube");

The error is expected and there will be none if desired element is present, but browser window is still invisible. I tried different versions of Chrome and Chromium but both are invisible. Geckobrowser is doing just perfect, but for my task I need Chrome-like browser. No other errors occur while doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using WebDriverManger

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
/*
 your code
*/
```

Comment: No improvements. It launches the chrome window but then instantly closes it and I have no idea how to catch the problem. try-catch catches nothing. Browser instance just vanishes.